# (WDK, C++, Windows) Is there a way to run process in kernel driver?

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, driver, wdk

i have a question for making a Kernel Driver

i hope to Run process using kernel driver when "notepad.exe" is started,

tried to using "PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine" and i successfully get a point what "notepad.exe" is launched.

but is there a way to run a "osk.exe" process in that point?

couldn't find code what i need to running it

i wanted to using this code "ZwOpenProcess" , "ZwOpenFile".

but there didn't enough what document to how to using it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot start a regular Windows process from kernel mode.

While `CreateProcess` does call into the kernel to create a process, after doing that it connects the new process to csrss.exe and this is required for many Windows APIs to work correctly.

Create a [service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-functions) that can create processes for your kernel code. Use the WTS API and `CreateProcessAsUser` to create the new process in the desired session. The driver should use [inverted callbacks](https://www.osr.com/nt-insider/2013-issue1/inverted-call-model-kmdf/).

If `PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine` is the only reason you are in the kernel then you can drop the driver and just use WMI in the service to get notifications about new processes...